# Yii2 выпадающее меню из базы данных multi menu from db

Tags: база-данных, yii2, menu

не могу понять как заполнить данными вложенное меню в yii2
вижу что оно формируется так.
Логично иметь две таблицы parentMenu(t1) и chaildMenu(t2)
в t1 foreign key -> (t1)chaild_id и в t2(parent_id) и как-то выбрать одним запросом или двумя, но как массив сформировать не понятно, вобщем запутался окончательно, подскажите как сделать?

```
    $menuItems = [
        ['label' => 'HOME', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'INFO', 'items' => [
            ['label' => 'About US', 'url' => ['/about-us/index']],
            ['label' => 'The Game', 'url' => ['/the-game/index']],
        ]],
        ['label' => 'PRICES', 'url' => ['/site/prices']],
        ['label' => 'FOO', 'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Foo', 'url' => ['/foo/index']],
```

У меня получается только одноуровневое меню из одной таблицы, а как сделать из двух, не могу понять.

```
 `$items = Menu::find()->all();
  foreach ($items as $item) {
     $result[] = [
          'label' => $item->title,
          'url' => [$item->url],
        ];
     }

  return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Две таблицы не надо делать. Если есть вложенность, то добавляем парент. После выборки строк из БД, саму выборку необходимо перемотать форичем (возможно прокатит использование ->indexBy('id'), не пробовал), чтобы сформировать массивы для вложенности.
А далее используем функцию-уроборос. Пример таков:

```
$row[] = ['id' => '1', 'parent' => '0', 'label' => 'HOME1', 'url' => 'home1'];
$row[] = ['id' => '2', 'parent' => '1', 'label' => 'HOME1-1', 'url' => 'home11'];
$row[] = ['id' => '3', 'parent' => '1', 'label' => 'HOME1-1', 'url' => 'home11'];
$row[] = ['id' => '4', 'parent' => '0', 'label' => 'HOME2', 'url' => 'home2'];
$row[] = ['id' => '5', 'parent' => '4', 'label' => 'HOME2-2', 'url' => 'home22'];
$row[] = ['id' => '6', 'parent' => '4', 'label' => 'HOME2-2', 'url' => 'home22'];
$row[] = ['id' => '7', 'parent' => '0', 'label' => 'HOME3', 'url' => 'home3'];
$row[] = ['id' => '8', 'parent' => '7', 'label' => 'HOME3-3', 'url' => 'home33'];
$row[] = ['id' => '9', 'parent' => '7', 'label' => 'HOME3-3', 'url' => 'home33'];

foreach($row as $r){
    $rows[$r['parent']][] = $r;
}

function tree($rows, $parent){

    $tre = '';
    if(isset($rows[$parent])){
        $tre = '<ul>';
        foreach($rows[$parent] as $row){

            $tre .= '<li>';
            $tre .= '<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['label'];
            $tre .= tree($rows, $row['id']);
            $tre .= '</a>';
            $tre .= '</li>';

        }
        $tre .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $tre;
}


echo '<pre>';
echo tree($rows, 0);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Сюда еще закинул https://pastebin.com/RBMzG9VJ

Comment: кажется чуток не то, вот этот массив (в моем вопросе), там не увсех парентов есть чилдрыны. и там получается нужно как бы проверку сделать есть ли чилдрыны или нет. Но я попробую ваш пример, спасибо.

Comment: tree проверяет наличие потомков. Если нету, то их и не получится разобрать функцией.